# ajaxPrefilter with Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

I develop a project using backbone, underscore, require .js and REST API.

I've got error `Cross-Origin Request Blocked The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at...`

**NOTE** : I've configured `Access-Control-Allow` in server side already. Still, the error still appear.

I found a solution, using `ajaxPrefilter`, then here I've tried in my project :

router.js :

```
start: function() {
        Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
},
initialize: function() {
   $.ajaxPrefilter( function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
            options.url = options.url;
        });
   }
```

Here is my backbone view :

```
var _wl = new MyModel();
_wl.save(_item,{
         success: function(res) {
             console.log(res);
         }
});
```

I still got `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://example.com/api/MyWebs. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

Could any one tell me what did I wrong here?

Any helps and ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: In your `ajaxPrefilter` the line `options.url = options.url` has no effect on the Ajax operation.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if the reponse from http://example.com/api/MyWebs carries back correctly configured CORS headers like "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" ,""Access-Control-Allow-Headers",""Access-Control-Allow-Methods" e.t.c. This can be done by having the dev tools open in chrome/firefox and inspecting the response headers.

Here are a couple of things to ensure if CORS has been configured properly:

Response Headers:

1. Check if you have configured the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header properly. Initially you  can set the value of it to  "*"  for testing purpose and then later on specify the specific host.
2. If you are using custom headers make sure that you have added them to the allowed list using "Access-Control-Allow-Headers". The custom headers names are specifed as a comma separated list.
3. If you want to support PUT,DELETE and POST requests with certain media types, then make sure that you add "Access-Control-Allow-Methods".

Server Side:

1. Check if you have added code to handle the pre-flight request that comes with OPTIONS method.

EG:

```
if(containerRequestContext.getRequest().getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS")) {
    // code to check if the request is made from a allowed origin and if everything is fine abort with success / forbidden.
}
```

2. Check if each response sent from the server is made with the above response headers correctly set.

EG:
Language/Framework: Jersey Framework,Java

Each response will pass thru the below Filter and the following response headers will be added to them.

```
@PreMatching
@Provider
public class SecurityResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(SecurityResponseFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext,ContainerResponseContext containerResponseContext) throws IOException {
        try {
            containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE"); 
            containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add( "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",  "tk_a,tk_r" );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error occured while processing request.",e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

3. In the client side if you need to send custom headers, you could do it as follows :

```js
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options,originalOptions,jqXHR) {
 jqXHR.setRequestHeader("tk_a",$.cookie("tk_a"));
 jqXHR.setRequestHeader("tk_r",$.cookie("tk_r"));
});
```